# Moving contents of Barracuda Archiver to Google Vault

Tags: email, google, barracuda

We are looking for a solution to help us move the contents of our Barracuda Email Archiver over to Google Vault. So far we have discovered TransVault (transvault.com). Does anyone know of any other options? Has anyone attempted such a move?